# C# .net 6 api project error calling Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an application in angular where the user logs in with MSAL and everything works, when the backend is called with authentication and authorization with the tokens, it works as expected, but when I try to call Microsoft Graph from C# in my EmployeeController (it's at the bottom of the post), I have the following errors:

(In this line: **var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();**)

[image]

I follow the next example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore

To make my code like this:

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
```

**Setup.cs:**

```
internal static class Setup
{
    internal static void AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration)
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(options => {
                options.Scopes = string.Join(' ', GraphConstants.Scopes);
            })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                //tenant validation with the token...
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
    }
}
```

**GraphConstants:**

```
internal static class GraphConstants
{
    // Defines the permission scopes used by the app
    internal readonly static string[] Scopes =
    {
            "User.Read"
    };

    internal const string UserReadScope = "User.Read";
}
```

**EmployeeController:**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<BrandController> logger;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;

    public EmployeeController(ILogger<BrandController> logger,
                             GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = GraphConstants.UserReadScope)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

            // Get user photo
            using (var photoStream = await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync())
            {
                byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
                var photo = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
            }
            return Ok(me);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, $"Error in [{nameof(EmployeeController)}][{nameof(GetAsync)}]");
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal Server Error. Something went Wrong in get the Employee!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Azure permissions:**
[image]

**Azure configuration:** I have two app registrations, one for the API and another for the front.
[image]

**Azure Overview of my Api:**
[image]

**AppSettings in application:**

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Scopes": "api.scope",
    "ClientId": "564c1201-.....",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "c366e412-.....",
    "ClientSecret": "........"
  },
```

Any clue what I'm missing?

Thank you in advance for the help :D

Comment: How many App Registrations do you have? You need one for your SPA and one for the "proxy" API. Are you sure you have properly set up AzureAd configuration section for your API?

Comment: Yeah, that's right I have the two app registrations, I (updated the post) put the configurations below Azure permissions.

Comment: You have a stand alone frontend Angular application and an asp.net core api project. and in this scenario, your api project should be recognized as the daemon app which is suitable for [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). but since you want the api to call graph api on behalf of the signed in user, so you should use [on behalf flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

Comment: on behalf flow [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph). if you want to use client credential flow, then you have to decode the access token you sent from the Angular client and decode it to get the user id, then you can use the user id to call ms graph api to get user information for that user.

Comment: @TinyWang Is right. You are authenticating user coming from SPA but you are not "impersonating" him. So when you try to call "Me" endpoint you actually identify as the service itself (not as a user). This will not work. You should potentially use the Users endpoint and provide search by principal name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, I decided to change the approach and use angular directly to call the graph API, I followed this video where you can see the step-by-step in detail.

Thank you very much for your answers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98T1CumHofI&t=2s